# Which solution does a particle follow if uniqueness fails in ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If there are multiple solutions to an ODE at y(0) = 0 and a particle is "dropped" into the flow field where the solutions intersect,which path does the particle take?  In other words, which solution do we follow if we start at (0,0)?

Comment: When solutions are not unique, it usually means your problem is not physical... that is, your differential equation or boundary conditions are inconsistent with anything that would actually be physically observed.

Comment: If you knew which solution to 'follow' it would be unique. The equation $\dot{x} = \sqrt{|x|}$ with $x(0) = 0$ is a standard example of an equation with multiple solutions.

Comment: Remark from talking with physicists. This is a problem for string theorists to solve.  Their equations do have nonunique solutions, and from what I have heard their answer is that what they physically observe is what has to be.

Answer (score 2):

The particle is real, the ODE is a model. Models are good as far as they go, but should not be confused with reality. If a model doesn't tell you what a particle does, it's a sign that (for the particular questions you ask) you need a better model. For that matter, $(0,0)$ is a model --- there is no $(0,0)$ in the real world.